# Swift AVPlayerViewController add target on playing video

Tags: swift, avplayerviewcontroller, addtarget

I am using AVPlayerViewController for playing video.The problem is that how can I detect the video is started to play? Usually is to addTarget but I cannot find any Target that I can add on that event. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this callback method **playerViewControllerDidStartPictureInPicture** from [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVKit/Reference/AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016157-CH1-DontLinkElementID_8)

eg

```
optional func playerViewControllerDidStartPictureInPicture(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController){
     //Called when Picture in Picture playback has started.
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. I do not want to add pic in pic functions. What I want is to detect the event that when users click the play button